# Default profile in Spring Boot is not getting selected in case of multiple profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Consider a simple example as follows:

1. I have a hierarchy of Pets as follows:

   ```
   public interface PetService{ .... }
   // Now this service is implemented by DogPetService and CatPerService as follows:

   @Service
   @Profile("cat")
   public class CatPetService implements PetService { ... }

   @Profile({"dog", "default"})
   @Service
   public class DogPetService implements PetService { ... }
   ```

As seen in the example, the `dog profile` is the **default**.

Now, I have another hierarchy as follows (in the same project). **Note:** This is something I am trying to learn and have no relevance to real world project.

```
   public interface GreetingService { ... }
   // The Greeting service is implemented by two classes as follows:
   
   @Profile({"EN", "default"} )
   @Service
   public class I18NEnglishGreetingService implements GreetingService { ... }
   
   @Profile("ES")
   @Service
   public class I18NSpanishGreetingService implements GreetingService { ... }
```

As seen, for the `GreetingService` - `I18NEnglishGreetingService` is the default Profile

Now, I have `application.properties` in which I am setting the active profiles as follows:

```
spring.profiles.active=ES
```

When I run the application, spring boot fails to start as it fails to find bean implementation for the PetService.

1. Why doesn't it fall back for the `DogPetService` which is the default profile?
2. In the `application.properties` if I add dog/cat, then it works fine.
3. If I completely remove the entry `spring.profiles.active` from the application.properties, then the both the default profiles are utilized...
4. If the entry `spring.profiles.active` is added, then is it mandatory to list all the required profiles? Why can't it detect that for some profiles, default is to be used?

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You yourself specify which profiles are active, this isn't additive but it replaces it. So if you specify none then the default profile, by default named `default` is active, else only the profile(s) as specified by you.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept and close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles)

> You can use a `spring.profiles.active` `Environment` property to specify which profiles are active. You can specify the property in any of the ways described earlier in this chapter. For example, you could include it in your `application.properties`, as shown in the following example:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb
```

> You could also specify it on the command line by using the following switch: `--spring.profiles.active=dev,hsqldb`.
> If no profile is active, a default profile is enabled. The name of the default profile is `default` and it can be tuned using the `spring.profiles.default` `Environment` property, as shown in the following example:

```
spring.profiles.default=none
```

You yourself specify which profiles are active, this isn't additive but it replaces it. So if you specify none then the default profile, by default named `default` (as shown above) is active, else only the profile(s) as specified by you